# Set value to true where cell value of row is the same as another row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel table I need to filter since it contains some partly duplicated data.

I have the three first columns (Group, Type and MayBeDuplicate) of the following table:

[image: excel screenshot]

What I don't have is the last column, **IsDuplicate**, but I want to create it. It should be set to TRUE when the following occurs:

1. The row has MayBeDuplicate set to true AND
2. The row's type value is the same of any other row's type value where Group is also the same for both rows.

That's it. I'm not experienced when it comes to this and I have a hard time setting the range for where to check without including the itself, making me end up with also the 5th row getting IsDuplicate set to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott's answer is checking if the values in columns A and B are the same.
I think you need a formula which checks if the group is the same for the records that have the same type, am I right?

For that situation you can use this code:

```
=AND(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)>1,C2=TRUE)
```

This code counts the amount of times the combination of group and type values occur. For example group 1 and type 1. If the combination occurs more than once, it's a duplicate. It also checks if the MayBeDuplicate is set to TRUE. When all this is TRUE, it returns the value TRUE, otherwise it'll return FALSE.

Comment: You are right. Your suggestion seems to be working as well. Thank you!

Comment: @Wouter Sorry for these confusing questions, but... What if I would have another column E "ExcludeFromFormula", that can be set to true or false. If this value is TRUE I want to exclude that row from the ranges in the COUNTIFS. How would I update the formula to satisfy that requirement?

Comment: Try this code `=AND(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2,E2,FALSE)>1,C2=TRUE)`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, but I think I can achieve what I want by doing this:     

    `=AND(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2,E:E;TRUE)>1,C2=TRUE)`

Results seem correct at least. Thank you for pointing out the way. Please let me know if you think my change is incorrect.

Comment: If you want to exclude the row when the value in E is TRUE, then I think you should change your formula to `=AND(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2,E:E;FALSE)>1,C2=TRUE)` (note I changed the `TRUE` in your formula to `FALSE` because you want to count it when it's `FALSE`).

Comment: @Wouter, this is a long shot, but do you know how I would have to create the code to get the same result with DAX syntax (where I don't have the COUNTIFS-function)? As I understand it the key is to use the CALCULATE, but I'm not sure how to.

Comment: Nope, sorry can't help you with that. And since it's a new question, you should create a new question.

Comment: True, I agree. Thank you for all the help though!